# Static member/class for generic repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

I have dapper generic repository class, since .net core does not support distributed transaction I have decided to send already opened connection object to generic method instead of injecting separately in the repository.

```
public class Repository<T> where T: class
{
    protected readonly IComplianceConnection Connection;

    public Repository(IComplianceConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Get(string query, object arguments)
    {
        IList<T> entities;

        using (var connection = Connection.OpenConnection())
        {
            entities = connection.Query<T>(query, arguments, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        }

        return entities;
    }
}
```

I need to change this to static class .below is the new repository.

```
public static class Repository<T> where T: class
{

    public static IEnumerable<T> Get(this IDbConnection connection, string query, object arguments)
    {
        IList<T> entities;


            entities = connection.Query<T>(query, arguments, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();


        return entities;
    }
}
```

Is this static method for generic repository correct? ..Pls suggest me

Comment: 1. I don't think the using is "appropriate" maybe the connection is already established ??. 2. Why you don't put this method on DbContext ?

Comment: Can u pls provide a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that extension methods act on an instance of a class. In your Get() method, that instance is the connection parameter. However, it seems like you are overwriting the connection instance in your Get() method. This may not be desired.

You probably don't want to create an extension method. Perhaps you just want a static method that can accept an IComplianceConnection parameter.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Get(IComplianceConnection complianceConnection, string query, object arguments)
{
    IList<T> entities;
    using (var connection = complianceConnection.OpenConnection())
    {
        entities = connection.Query<T>(query, arguments, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    }
    return entities;
}
```

Hope this helps!